# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un while en un for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, while

¿Alguna idea de cómo se puede convertir el siguiente bucle while en un for?

```
 while True:
    if(y >= Columna):
        y=0
        x = x + 1
    if (x >= filas):
        x = 0
    if (arreglo[x, y] == buscar[a]):
        posX.append(x)
        posY.append(y)
        a=a+1
        cont=0
    if(a>=len(buscar)):
        encontro=True
        break
    cont=cont+1
    y = y + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te han dicho, los bucles for no tienen como objetivo ser infinitos, sino recorrer una lista. Por tu código, me da la sensación de que intentas recorrer la lista "buscar" porque manualmente le dices que cuando llegue hasta el final (el contador sea igual a la longitud) corte el bucle. Eso te lo ahorras con el for, así:

```
for b in buscar:
  """ donde b equivaldría a buscar[a] sin tener que usar a como contador """
```

Si explicas como tienes los datos y cual es el objetivo, podemos ayudarte a formularlo.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no encuentro un motivo para hacerlo, si quieres crear un *for infinito* podrías iterar sobre una lista que crece en cada iteración. Por ejemplo:

```py
lista = [0]

for i in lista:
    print(i)
    lista.append(lista[-1] + 1)
```

En este ejemplo el *bucle for* es infinito. Puedes escapar de él con `break`.

En cualquier caso, **este código no es aconsejable**. Estarías creando una lista enorme que no tiene ninguna utilidad.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Si quisieras hacer un **for infinito** sin necesidad de crear listas infinitas, puedes usar el truco siguiente:

```
from itertools import cycle
infinito = cycle([1])
```

Eso crea un iterable infinito (porque cicla sobre sí mismo), con el cual puedes cambiar un `while True` por un `for`:

```
i = 0
for _ in infinito:
  print("Foo")
  i+=1
  if i==5:
    break
```

Con un truco así no necesitas cambiar nada en tu código, salvo el `while True:` que cambiará a `for _ in infinito:`, pero sospecho que **no es este el objetivo del ejercicio**, sino que cambies la lógica del programa para que use un bucle for *no infinito*.

En este caso necesitarías aclarar cuál es el objetivo del código. ¿Debe quizás encontrar cada elemento de la lista `buscar` en la matriz `arreglo` y generar listas con las coordenadas en que se encontró? ¿puede tener `buscar` elementos repetidos? ¿Y `arreglo`?

Creo que todo quedaría más claro si pones un ejemplo de lo que contienen `arreglo` y `buscar` y de la salida que esperas.